# Return rows that are at the intersection of two lists using query function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
pd.DataFrame([[1, "type_1"], [2, "type_2"], [2, "type_1; type_2"], [2, "type_1; type_3"], [2, "type_3"], [2, "type_1; type_2, type_3"]],
                     columns=["a", "b"])
    a   b
0   1   type_1
1   2   type_2
2   2   type_1; type_2
3   2   type_1; type_3
4   2   type_3
5   2   type_1; type_2, type_3
```

and I need to use lots of query strings that I get from a config file, that look like these:

```
my_list = ["type_1", "type_2"]
df.query("a == 2 and b in @my_list")
```

Now this outputs:

```
    a   b
1   2   type_2
```

But I would want the output to be like this because at least one value from b is in my_list:

```
    a   b
0   2   type_2
1   2   type_1; type_2
2   2   type_1; type_3
3   2   type_1; type_2, type_3
```

The issue as you can see is that **some of my columns are actually lists**. At the moment they are strings separated by `;` but I can transform them into lists. However I'm not sure how this would help me filter rows that have at least one value from `column b` inside `my_list` **using only .query()** (because otherwise I'll have to parse the query string and it gets messy)

This would be the equivalent code with lists:

```
pd.DataFrame([[1, ["type_1"]], [2, ["type_2"]], [2, ["type_1", "type_2"]], [2, ["type_1", "type_3"]], [2, "type_3"], [2, ["type_1", "type_2", "type_3"]]],
                     columns=["a", "b"])
```

Comment: @coldspeed no solution even if my b column has values as lists?

Comment: Not with query. What I can suggest is to do that check separately using `str.contains` and AND the mask. Are you interested in seeing how this is done?

Comment: @coldspeed yes.

Comment: @coldspeed do you know if pandas is usually open for a PR that does this (in case you've contributed to the library)

Comment: I was wrong; this _is_ supported. Check my edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I was wrong. Looks like this *is* supported with the "python" engine.

```
df.query("a == 2 and b.str.contains('|'.join(@my_list))", engine='python')

   a                       b
1  2                  type_2
2  2          type_1; type_2
3  2          type_1; type_3
5  2  type_1; type_2, type_3
```

---

(Old Answer) Your query can be split into two parts: The part that requires a substring check, and everything else.

You can compute two mask separately. I recommend using `str.contains` and `DataFrame.eval`. You can then AND the masks and filter `df`.

```
m1 = df.eval("a == 2")
m2 = df['b'].str.contains('|'.join(my_list))

df[m1 & m2]

   a                       b
1  2                  type_2
2  2          type_1; type_2
3  2          type_1; type_3
5  2  type_1; type_2, type_3
```

Comment: oh my God awesome, i was beginning to lose hope :)

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga Learned something new today, thanks for the question :)

Answer (score 3):

You can using `str.split` before re-create your list like columns and using `isin` and `any`.Notice `isin` is exact match , which mean if you hvae `type_11` , using `isin` it will return `False`

```
df[(pd.DataFrame(df.b.str.split(';').tolist()).isin(my_list).any(1))&(df.a==2)]
Out[88]: 
   a                       b
1  2                  type_2
2  2          type_1; type_2
3  2          type_1; type_3
5  2  type_1; type_2, type_3
```

Comment: You should take into account the "a == 2" condition as well.